# How to get new version of payment module For OC 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart

I have a question. I am building webshop in opencart and have a payment module to integrate. Module is now in version 1.5.x.x. but I have a version of OC 2.0.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

If the module is not written for OC v2 yet then you'd need to write it yourself or hire a developer to write it.